# Finding duplicate invoices

Tags: performance, groovy

I have a `invoiceList` which is a `List<Map<String:String>>` and am trying to find out if all the invoices have same `SENDER_COUNTRY` and `CLIENT_COUNTRY` or not. If not, it will add the message to a JSON array.

```
[
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:USA, CLIENT_COUNTRY:USA]
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:CAD, CLIENT_COUNTRY:MEX]
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:CAD, CLIENT_COUNTRY:MEX]
]

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
def senderCountry = invoiceList[0]['SENDER_COUNTRY']
def clientCountry  = invoiceList[0]['CLIENT_COUNTRY']
invoiceList.each{ it ->
if(it['SENDER_COUNTRY'] != senderCountry)
  jsonArray.add((new JSONObject()).put("SENDER_COUNTRY","Multiple sender Countries Associated"));
 if(it['CLIENT_COUNTRY'] != clientCountry)
  jsonArray.add((new JSONObject()).put("CLIENT_COUNTRY","Multiple Client Countries Associated"));
}
```

I feel this code can be refactored/optimized to a better version in Groovy. Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

Putting the JSONArray aside (given I don't know the fully qualified name of the class), here's a Groovy-er version:

## Working example

```
def invoiceList = [
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617151,SENDER_COUNTRY:'USA', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'USA'],
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617152,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX'],
    [INVOICE_DATE:20150617, INVOICE_NUMBER:617153,SENDER_COUNTRY:'CAD', CLIENT_COUNTRY:'MEX']
]

def senderCountry = invoiceList[0]['SENDER_COUNTRY']
def clientCountry  = invoiceList[0]['CLIENT_COUNTRY']

def result = invoiceList.inject([:]) { status, invoice ->
    if(invoice['SENDER_COUNTRY'] != senderCountry) status << ["SENDER_COUNTRY": "Multiple sender Countries Associated"]
    if(invoice['CLIENT_COUNTRY'] != clientCountry) status << ["CLIENT_COUNTRY":"Multiple Client Countries Associated"]

    status
}

if(result) {
    println "Not all invoices have the same sender and client countries."
} else {
    println "All good"
}
```

## How it works

The `inject()` method iterates through the `invoiceList` and calls a closure with an object to aggregate with and the current item in the list. Iteration begins with an empty `Map` as the aggregated object, which remains empty unless the un-matching countries are found. When a mismatch occurs, it is recorded in the `Map`. The closure purposely returns the `Map` because the output of the closure is what's fed back in during the next iteration.

Finally, if the resulting `Map` is empty, then all of the countries are the same. Otherwise, the `Map` contains one or two keys indicating what the problem was.

If all you really need to know is whether all the countries matched or not, you can simply use `every()`:

```
def result = invoiceList.every { invoice ->
    invoice['SENDER_COUNTRY'] == senderCountry && invoice['CLIENT_COUNTRY'] == clientCountry
}
```